# SQL Query Help obtaining last order date from 2 tables

Tags: sql

I have the following table

```
Orders_All
Account
```

Orders all contains every order line many thousand records and the 2 records are `order_date` and `order_account_id`.

This need to join into the Account so other queries can be run as well but I want a report that shows the account_id and the last order date but only one record per account.

How can I create a query to acgieve this.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT account_id, MAX(order_date) as last_order_date FROM Orders_All INNER JOIN Account ON order_account_id = account_id GROUP BY account_id`

That will give you the account ID and the maximum (furthest in the future) date.  The `GROUP BY` is what limits it - it's the maximum date "for each" account_id.

If an account has no orders and you still want that account to show, with a `NULL` in the date column, use a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` there.

Comment: Please note: you can get multiple rows per account if there are multiple orders on the same day (and that day also happens to be the max).

Comment: No, you can't, it selects the maximum date and groups on account_id.  Guaranteed one record per account_id.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select accound_id,Max(OrderDate) from Order_All t1,AccountID t2
where t1.AccountID = t2.AccountID
group by account_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Subtitute * for the columns you want to show or leave it and try the next code.

```
select distinct * from Account A
join Orders_All O on O.order_account_id = A.account_id
--so far we have join both table, so we need the last order date from it
where o.order_date in (select MAX(order_date) from Orders_All)
--in where clause im getting max order date from table Orders_All
```

> but what if I want last order date by customer?

Well then you could write this (not the best but it works):

```
select * 
  from Account A
  join (select account_id as Acc_id, MAX(order_date) as Date 
          from Orders_All 
         group by account_id) 
    as OD on A.account_id = OD.Acc_id
```